# Rails 3.1 assets not resolving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

**Problem**

I have a Rails 3.0.4 app which I upgrade to 3.1.4 following instructions from [Railscast video: "Upgrading to rails 3.1"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1).

Now I have problems with **assets** because they **are not resolved**, giving messages in server log like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-08 03:57:13 -0500
Served asset /application.css - 404 Not Found (15ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.css"):
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/actionpack-3.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (14.3ms)

Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-08 03:57:13 -0500
Served asset /application.js - 404 Not Found (35ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.js"):
```

These files are in `assets` directory:

```
$ ls app/assets/*/application*
app/assets/javascripts/application.js   app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

and contains this:

```
$ cat app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
$ cat app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

I suppose everything is configured. Here I put some chunks of files:

- `Gemfile`, contains assets gems required:

  ```
  group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
    gem 'uglifier'
  end
  ```
- `application.rb`, has assets enabled:

  ```
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  ```
- `development.rb`:

  ```
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  ```
- finally... `application.html.erb` layout:

  ```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  ```

**Stage**

I am now in **development** environment.

**Tests**

1. If I request `http://localhost:3000/assets/images/rails.png`, it throws `No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/rails.png"`, but file is there:

   ```
   $ ls app/assets/images/rails.png 
   app/assets/images/rails.png
   ```
2. Then I execute `rake assets:precompile`:

   ```
   $ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
   ```

   Then, execute server (`rails s`) and request again an image (`rails.png`):

   ```
   $ rails s
   => Booting WEBrick
   => Rails 3.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
   => Call with -d to detach
   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/actionpack-3.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:101: warning: already initialized constant PDF
   [2012-04-08 04:53:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
   [2012-04-08 04:53:06] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2012-02-14) [i686-linux]
   [2012-04-08 04:53:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=16702 port=3000

   Started GET "/assets/images/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-08 04:53:14 -0500
   Served asset /images/rails.png - 404 Not Found (38ms)

   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/rails.png"):

   Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/actionpack-3.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (125.2ms)
   ```

So **What's wrong?**, Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this only in production mode? Have you run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`? Also, do you have the sprockets library included?

Comment: @pjumble Not yet, Is that necessary even if I am under development environment?

Comment: I assumed you were in production mode, but no, in development mode you don't have to precompile the assets. If you remove `/images/` from the URL does the image work? (`http://localhost:3000/assets/rails.png`)

Comment: @pjumble It works! `http://localhost:3000/assets/rails.png` Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all precompiled assets are moved to the assets folder.

That means the content of javascript, stylesheets AND images will be combined in `localhost:3000/assets`.

So if you search for 
`localhost:3000/assets/images/rails.png` 
it should be located in 
`app/assets/images/images/rails.png`.
Therefor the 404.

To keep your directory clean I suggest to keep all your images in app/assets/images/ and point to them with `asset_path('rails.png')`